# get_googlemap() function doesn't display correct positions

Tags: r, ggmap

I am using `GoogleMaps` API in *R*.
I have tried to run this code:

```
lon_lat <- transmute(df, longitude=round(longitude, 2), latitude=round(latitude, 2))
map <- get_googlemap(location="mexico", markers=lon_lat, scale=2, key=key)
ggmap(map)
```

but it displays the map of the city of Houston, without markers.

Also, I have tried to convert `lon_lat` in spatial coordinates by:

```
library(sp)
SpatialPoints(lon_lat)
```

But I get the same wrong map of Houston.

I suppose that the issue is about spatial coordinates, but I'm not sure of this.

**EDIT :**

These are the first five spatial coordinates from `loc_lat`:
[image]

Comment: @MarcoSandri I have added longitude and latitude data description, I hope that this could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right sintax for `get_googlemap`:

```
lon_lat <- read.table(text='
longitude latitude
-99.24 18.93
-101.2 22.14
-99.23 18.92
-101.00 22.15
-101.01 22.15
', header=T)

library(ggmap)    
map <- get_googlemap(center=c(lon=-100, lat=20), zoom = 7) 

ggmap(map) +
geom_point(data=lon_lat, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude) , color="red", size=3)
```

[image]